# How to prevent MsAjax scripts from loading on ASP.NET WebForms project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I created an ASP.NET 4.7.1 WebForms web application project.

- I removed all references to ~/Scripts/WebForms and ~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax in BundleConfig.cs.
- I removed the NuGet packages for Microsoft.AspNet.ScriptManager.MSAjax and Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjax
- I did an 'Edit > Find in Files' for "msajax" on the entire project, and nothing was found.

When I load any page on my site, ~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js and ~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js both still load. You can see them in HTML source and see that they get loaded in standard browser developer tools. I don't need them (as far as I know), and I don't want them wasting my bandwidth (over 140KB each pageload).

Obviously I can delete the files themselves, but then I just get HTTP 404 errors in my logs.

Comment: Check if these files are being served from browser cache? On chrome, open dev tools and then go to Network tab under which you can see if these js files are coming from cache.

Comment: @Sunil The .aspx page is not coming from cache. The .js files do come from cache after their first load (as they should).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent MsAjax scripts from loading on page you need to set property `AjaxFrameworkMode` to `Disabled`

**Markup**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" AjaxFrameworkMode="Disabled" ScriptMode="Release" runat="server">
    <CompositeScript ScriptMode="Release">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" />
        </Scripts>
    </CompositeScript>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

**Code behind**

```
ScriptManager.AjaxFrameworkMode = AjaxFrameworkMode.Disabled;
```

Comment: @A_HREF Thanks for taking the time to answer an old question. It was still ongoing for me and this solved it.